# Server response to put with c# socket

Tags: c#, http, sockets, webserver, webclient

I have following server code:

```
class Program
{

    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8000));

        server.Listen();


        while (true)
        {
            Socket client = server.Accept();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(new 
            NetworkStream(client));
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            string eof = new string(new char[] { (char)10, (char)13, 
            (char)10 });

            while (!buffer.ToString().Contains(eof))
            buffer = buffer.Append((char)streamReader.Read());

            Console.WriteLine(buffer);
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new 
            NetworkStream(client));

            streamWriter.WriteLine();
            streamWriter.Flush();


        }

    }

    static string createResponse()
    {
        string s = @"
        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        Date: " + DateTime.Now + @"
        Server: Custom
        Connection: keep-alive
        Allow: OPTIONS, GET, PUT
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
        Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
        Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
        Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true";

        return s;
    }
}
```

And following client code (javascript):

```
function connect() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000', 
    {
        method: 'put',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type" : "text/html"
        },
        body: "Test"
    });

}
```

I get following output in server:

```
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

But nowhere can I find the body, or even the content-type/length in the received client header - why? What exactly am I doing wrong? I tried to set the stream position to zero AFTER sending the server header (although it makes no sense at all, because its a network stream), but as expected it threw an error. How exactly does the HTTP protocol work with regards to the PUT method? What has the server to provide, in order to establish a correct exchange between server and client?

Answer (score 0):

Thank God, here the solution:

```
class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8000));

            server.Listen(int.MaxValue);


            while (true)
            {
                Socket client = server.Accept();
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(new NetworkStream(client));
                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                string eof = new string(new char[] { (char)10, (char)13, (char)10 });

                while (!buffer.ToString().Contains(eof))
                    buffer = buffer.Append((char)streamReader.Read());



                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new NetworkStream(client));
                streamWriter.WriteLine(createCORSHeader());
                streamWriter.Flush();


                int contentLength = 0;

                var lines = buffer.ToString().Split('\n');
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    var keyValuePair = lines[i].Split(':');
                    if (keyValuePair.Length < 2)
                        continue;

                    var key = keyValuePair[0];
                    var val = keyValuePair[0 + 1].Substring(1, keyValuePair[1].Length - 1);

                    if (key.Equals("Content-Length"))
                        contentLength = int.Parse(val);
                }


                buffer.Clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < contentLength; i++)
                    buffer.Append((char)streamReader.Read());



                File.AppendAllText("protokoll.txt", "[" + DateTime.Now + "]\t" + buffer.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);


                streamWriter.WriteLine(createPUTResponse());
                streamWriter.Flush();


                client.Close();

                Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            }

        }

        static string createCORSHeader()
        {
            string s = @"
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Origin
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
";

            return s;
        }


        static string createPUTResponse()
        {
            string s = @"
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Origin
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
";

            return s;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? This is far from a compliant HTTP server. Why not use HttpListener, ASP.NET Core MVC or one of the many alternatives out there?